# Django Custom Admin Panel Site Settings

Tags: python, django

For my learning I am making a forum style site in Django. Previously, I created a class based view for logging in and registering users. For the next step, I am hoping to complete the admin control panel (not the Django one; a custom one for the forum). There I want to be able to set site settings. For example, the default theme, etc. I am not sure how to proceed with this, any code or tutorial links will be taken.

Comment: Creating your own custom admin page is like creating any normal website, the only difference being the use of permission tag to restrict use to your custom admin page. Everything else is normal functions which you can find in any normal django tutorial, for example use forms to setup users, or delete users, change themes (need appropriate models etc for all of them...

Answer (score 1):

Here are some great resources to get you started on customizing the Django admin and some more in depth pieces as well as packages that can help you along the way. Remember that the admin interface was meant to be extended. Best of luck!

[Django AdminPlus](https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus) lets you add admin views that are not tied to models. This package is lightweight and tacks onto the existing admin site.

[Nexus](https://github.com/YPlan/nexus) is a pluggable admin application for Django that helps give you simple design and architecture. This is actively maintained by Disqus.

[Here's an article](http://blog.montylounge.com/2009/07/05/customizing-the-django-admin-branding/) on how to get started customizing the style of the admin and is helpful for getting your feet wet on how to make changes.

[Here is a more in depth article](http://book.huihoo.com/django/en/1.0/chapter17/index.html) about customizing the admin interface and the philosophy behind what it represents and the assumptions that were made when initially creating it.